# Bound for a geometric sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $a>1$ and $0<x<1$ are fixed then there exist constants $c,c'$ such that
$$  c\sum_{n=0}^N a^{nx} \leq (\sum_{n=0}^N a^n)^x \leq c' \sum_{n=0}^N a^{nx}$$
for all $N$, as one can see by looking at the quotient $(\sum_{n=0}^N a^n)^x/\sum_{n=0}^N a^{nx}$, which has finite, non-zero limit as $N\to\infty$.

> Is it true that  $$(\sum_{n\in F} a^n )^x \sim \sum_{n\in F} a^{nx}$$
>   for all finite subsets $F$ of $\mathbb N$? (Where $\sim$ means that
>   there exist constants $c,c'$ as above...)

Note that one direction is easy since we always have
$$(\sum_{n\in F} a^n )^x  \leq \sum_{n\in F} a^{nx}$$
For the other direction, Holder's inequality gives something weaker
$$\sum_{n\in F} a^{nx}\leq (\sum_{n\in F}a^{n})^x (\sum_{n\in F}1)^{1-x}=(\sum_{n\in F}a^n)^x (\#F)^{1-x} $$
where $1/x, 1/(1-x)$ are the dual exponents in Holder's. However, this is a bound depending on $\#F$, i.e. the cardinality of $F$.

Is there a counterexample to what I'm trying to show?

Comment: I don't $a=2$, $x=1/2$, $F=\{1,3,...,2n+1\}$ is a counter example like you say. I get $\frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \leq (\sum_{n\in F} a^n )^x / \sum_{n\in F} a^{nx} \leq 1$.

Comment: Ah my miscomputation!

Comment: By trying some cases in wolframalpha, I see that the lower bound decreases to $0$ as $x\to 0$ (but we are not interested in that). Also, as the gaps of the numbers increase e.g. take $F=\{ 1,2k,3k,\dots,kn\}$ for $k=1,2,\dots$, then the lower bound seems to increase to $1$.

Comment: My conjecture is that the lower bound is a function of the largest gap of the integers in $F$, i.e. if we write $F=\{n_1<\dots<n_k\}$, then we are looking at $\max \{n_m-n_{m-1}\}$. The largest possible value is achieved when we are summing consecutive integers, i.e. $F=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, and the least possible value is $1$, and is achieved as the gap approaches $\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is hidden at the observation in the comment. The gaps in $F$ are what matters, so I came up with the following proof:

If $N=\max\{n:n\in F\}$, then

$$ \frac{\sum_{n\in F} a^{nx}}{(\sum_{n\in F}a^n)^x}\leq \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}a^{nx}+a^{Nx}}{a^{Nx}}$$
$$= \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}a^{(n-N)x}+1=\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{a^{xk}}+1$$
$$\leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty (\frac{1}{a^x})^k+1$$
$$=\frac{1}{1-a^{-x}}+1$$
This is not the best bound but we were expecting to have something bigger than $1$, approaching $\infty$ as $x\to 0$ (see the comments).